# Class and while loop?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so I'm sorry if I've made any silly mistake. I have a class with a method *isSorted()*. I want this method to return True if two lists (a and b) are the same:

```
class Puzzle:
  def isSorted(self):
    return set(self.a) == set(self.b)
```

I use this method outside the class, like this:

```
puzzle = Puzzle()

while puzzle.isSorted():
  #do things
```

The loop never ends. Is there any way I could solve this, and is it bad code? I've tried

```
puzzleIsSorted = puzzle.isSorted()
```

outside the class and re-assigning it in the while loop, but it still didn't work.

edit: full code:

```
import random

class Puzzle:

  def __init__(self):
    self.f = open("file.txt", "r")
    self.a = self.f.readlines()

    self.b = self.a
    random.shuffle(self.b)

  def swapLine(self, line):
    self.b[len(self.b) - 1], self.b[line] = self.b[line], self.b[len(self.b) - 1]

  def isSorted(self):
    return set(self.a) == set(self.b)

puzzle = Puzzle()  
moveCount = 0

print `puzzle.b`

while not puzzle.isSorted():
  x = input("Enter a line to swap: ")
  puzzle.swapLine(x)
  print "\n" + `puzzle.b`

print "Game over in " + `moveCount` + " moves"
```

Comment: How are you passing in your sets? Is this all the code?

Comment: I'll edit the question in a minute, I tried adding the code to the comment but it didn't work.

Comment: `#do things`, what things?

Comment: I added the full code in my question.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong title, I don't know why it was like that.

Comment: What do you expect this `set(self.a) == set(self.b)` to do?

Comment: To return True if the two arrays have the same elements in the same order, but reading more about the set() function I realised that is wrong.

Comment: OP wants it to return a boolean

Comment: Just an FYI: you can use negative list indices, so `self.b[len(self.b) - 1]` can be simplified to `self.b[-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you must copy the list to make a new one in `Puzzle`'s `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.f = open("file.txt", "r")
    self.a = self.f.readlines()

    # you must copy the list to make another list
    self.b = self.a[:]

    random.shuffle(self.b)
```

In your method:

```
def isSorted(self):
    return set(self.a) == set(self.b)
```

The condition is always `True` since you only swap lines, you do not add or delete them. `set`s do not care for order.

If you want to check for order you can drop the set:

```
def isSorted(self):
    return self.a == self.b
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I've done that the first time I tried it.

Comment: added more info to answer

Answer (score 3):

You were *very* close.  Make two changes. 1) Don't use sets, stick with lists because they make sure the order matters whereas sets ignore ordering.  2) Be sure to make a copy of the list using slicing rather than an assignment to *b*.  The current code makes *a* and *b* aliases for the same list.

Here's some working code to get you started:

```
import random

text = '''\
Dog
Fox
Cat
Rat
Jay
'''

class Puzzle:

  def __init__(self):
    self.a = text.splitlines()

    self.b = self.a[:]           # <== Fixed:  Make a copy using slicing
    random.shuffle(self.b)

  def swapLine(self, line):
    self.b[len(self.b) - 1], self.b[line] = self.b[line], self.b[len(self.b) - 1]

  def isSorted(self):
    return self.a == self.b      # <== Fixed:  Don't use sets

puzzle = Puzzle()  
moveCount = 0

print `puzzle.b`

while not puzzle.isSorted():
  x = random.randrange(5)        # <== Made this automatic for testing purposes
  puzzle.swapLine(x)
  print `puzzle.b`
  moveCount += 1                 # <== Fixed:  Update the move counter

print "Game over in " + `moveCount` + " moves"
```